# Issue while sending the mail using cdo configuration in vb script

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, smtp

I have a requirement that I need to send mails from excel. We are using MS Excel for doing some functionalities and it will generate a report after the executing all the steps.

The folder structure is below.

A=>(report.html , A1,A2,A3)
 A{0} is a folder inside A (main folder) and has report.html in each folder.
    The main report , basically contains link to all other reports.  User can view the sub reports.

Till this , it working fine.

Next Requirement is to Zip the folder A, so that all other folders are available in that zip. That’s also working.

Finally we need to send the zip file to a given mail ID. Here is the issue.

I am attaching the vbs file, which I used to send the mail. But its behaving differently on different network.

On office network                                          :               CDO.Message.1: The transport failed to connect to the server.

On Client network (using Citrix)                :               CDO.Message.1: The transport failed to connect to the server.

On Home Network                                         :               It’s worked and I got the mail.

SMTP Settings
   Server –  smtp.office365.com
   Port – 587 (also tried with 25)
   SSL -  true (according to Office 365 they are using TSL)

How to identify the issue ?

Code below.

```
Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1 'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory. 
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network). 

Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
objMessage.Subject = "Example CDO Message" 
objMessage.From = "$MailID$" 
objMessage.To = "$ToID$" 
objMessage.TextBody = "This is some sample message text.." & vbCRLF & "It was sent using SMTP authentication."

'==This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "$SMTPServer$"

'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic

'Your UserID on the SMTP server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "$MailID$"

'Your password on the SMTP server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "$Password$"

'Server port (typically 25)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = $PortNo$ 

'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

'Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection to the SMTP server)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 10000

'objMessage.Addattachment "D:\Vn\POC\attachfile.txt"

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

'==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

objMessage.Send
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a case of permissions, where you have access to the `SMTP` server at your `home` network, but not on the `office` or `client` network. If it works perfectly on your `home` network then i would expect it to be something of this nature. So if you need to run this from the office, i would speak with your IT Admin to find out which group are granted access to the `SMTP` server.

Also from a coding point of view does your code use all of the `CONST` declarations?, i can see 5 declarations but only 1 (2 see below) used

Should this line of code not = 2, but = cdoNTLM

`objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2`

Comment: exactly you are correct about the usage of constants, Its an edited one for posting for SO and the original one , I have the constants. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Thanks, did you check that it was/wasn't the permissions?

Comment: is there any way that we can ensure that its not working due to security privileges, without going to sec team ?

Comment: Sure, you have said that it works on home network. So it sounds like it is not a syntax issue. I would firstly check that both versions of vbscript/wscript are the same/similar. You can google how to do this. If this is still the same i would conclude that it is security access. I had the same problem with non connection to stmp server and when i was granted access it worked. This is why i believe this is the likely cause. Thanks